# Ionic2 - Native Scroll

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

Ionic1 can use the native scroll to improve the performance of the app using this code

```
$ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);
```

How can I do the same in Ionic2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you can find [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/native-scrolling-in-ionic-2/45871)

> Happy to say that Ionic 2 is 100% native scrolling since day 1