# Ionic 2 Native Scroll in Android

Tags: android, animation, scroll, ionic2

In Ionic 1 there was API for scrolling and Animations like Bounce in Android for Native Feel of Scrolling.

In Ionic 2 I can't find any mention of this API or Animations in Docs. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463652/ionic2-native-scroll) SO question but there isn't any detail.

I'm building Template Apps with these specs (Result of `ionic info` command):

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.11.0
OS         : Windows 10
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 3.10.10
```

and Tested on Real Devices and with `ionic serve` but scroll is just like a web page. No bouncing or Animation. I have searched the internet but nothing on Bouncing, Scroll, Native Scroll Animation in Ionic 2.

I have also tried Ionic 1 attrs for ion content:

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" has-bouncing="true" >
```

but no good.

Comment: Any findings on this topic?

Comment: I only came up with `<ion-content has-bouncing>` . I doesn't really bounce in android but It seems to smooth out scroll somewhat. But not as good though as It should be.